# Unable to convert CFStringRef to NSString with __bridge

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

Kindly bear if it is a very basic question. I tried to convert CFStringRef to NSString using __bridge, as i have enabled ARC.

```
mydevUUIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, peripheral.UUID);
 NSString *temp = (__bridge NSString *) devUUIDString;
```

I'm still getting the following error:

```
 Incompatible type casting 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString  **) to 'NSString' with _bridge cast.
```

Kindly advice, how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please enter the actual code. Your code snippet above wouldn't even compile (the variables have different names in your snippet, for example).

Comment: You use different variables `mydevUUIDString` / `devUUIDString` in both lines.

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete. Where is devUUIDString defined and assigned to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you create `mydevUUIDString`, you create it as a pointer to a CFStringRef. For example, when I enter the following code, Xcode gives me no errors:

```
CFStringRef mydevUUIDString = NULL;
NSString *temp = (__bridge NSString *)(mydevUUIDString);
```

However, when I enter this code (which is most likely what you've done):

```
CFStringRef *mydevUUIDString = NULL;
NSString *temp = (__bridge NSString *)(mydevUUIDString);
```

I get the same error you get:

> Incompatible type casting 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString  **) to 'NSString' with _bridge cast.